# Не могу удалить таблицы, связанные ключом

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть таблички:

```
create table "user" (
    id serial not null constraint account_pkey primary key,
    email text not null,
    password text not null,
);

create table user_role (
    user_id integer not null constraint account_role_account_id_fkey references "user",
    role_id integer not null,
    created_at timestamp(0) default timezone('UTC'::text, now()) not null,
    constraint account_role_pkey primary key (user_id, role_id)
);
```

Хочу удалить юзера. Делаю так:

```
DELETE FROM "user" CASCADE;
```

Получаю

```
update or delete on table "user" violates foreign key constraint "account_role_account_id_fkey" on table "user_role"
```

В чём причина?

Comment: *Делаю так: `DELETE FROM "user" CASCADE;`* - синтаксис [DELETE statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html) не предусматривает опции `CASCADE` (даже слова такого на странице нету...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CASCADE используется при создании FOREIGN KEY, чтобы при удалении или изменении инфы в материнской таблице изменения учитывались и в дочерней.
Если вы не сделали этого заранее, то сейчас скорее всего надо дропнуть текущий foreign key и создать новый, примерно таким образом:

1.

```
ALTER TABLE "table"
DROP CONSTRAINT "constraint"
```

2. 

```
ALTER TABLE "table"
ADD CONSTRAINT "constraint"
FOREIGN KEY ("column name") REFERENCES "table2"("column name") ON DELETE CASCADE
```